# Smartface in action doesnt show up map

Tags: mobile, android-maps-v2, smartface.io

I've installed smartface in action app on my samsung note 3 android device but when i click to the Map button the app does not show up any map or object inside the map window. I've recovered my phone to the factory settings and login to the google services again but there is no any difference. Is something going wrong? Can we work with map in smartface successfuly?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna work with map object in Smartface App Studio, you should take a map api token from Google Developer Console. And put this token into the manifest file. It is an obligation. By the way, do not forget that you will never run the map object in the emulator even if you got a token. You have to publish your application in the store. Here is a manifest example below.

```
<meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="YOUR_MAP_API_TOKEN"/>
```